# Gateaux Derivative and Directional Derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, analysis, operator-theory

It's a quite well-known fact that the Gateaux Derivative is a generalization of the Directional Derivative, since it holds for locally convex topological vector spaces ,while the directional only holds for the Euclidian.

But let's look at their definitions. The Gateaux derivative is defined as:
\begin{equation}
df(u,\psi)=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(u+\epsilon\psi)-f(u)}{\epsilon}=\dfrac{d}{d\epsilon}f(u+\epsilon\psi)\Bigg|_{\epsilon=0}
\end{equation}

While the directional derivative is defined as:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_v{f(\mathbf{x})}=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(\mathbf{x}+hv)-f(\mathbf{x})}{h}
\end{equation}

Where ${v}=({v}_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,{v}_n)$ is a vector from $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x}_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,\mathbf{x}_n)$, is a scalar function om $\mathbf{x}$.

I honestly do not understand what's the fundamental difference in these definitions, of course, you could simply tell me that the parameters in the Gateaux Derivative do not have the constraints of the terms on the Directional Derivative, but that would be a tautological argument.

So, summarizing, that's my question: What does the Gateaux Derivative "brings" that allows it to be extended to topological spaces? I mean, it's a huge gap, since the Directional only holds on $\mathbb{R}^n$, a piece of vector spaces, and the other one is valid on a much broader range, so I expect to have a clear difference. If anyone can help me out, I'll be grateful.

Comment: There's no fundamental difference apart from names. It's the exact same limit; only the domains/target spaces are modified. In fact, when I learned this material, I did not even know about Gateaux, or that this derivative was named after him. I only used the term "directional derivative" even when the domain/target where arbitrary Banach spaces (of course, the definitions can be extended verbatim to topological vector spaces)

Comment: But that's what I do not get: Why don't the usual definition of Directional Derivatives hold for Banach Spaces? I understand the constraints in the definition, but it seems that in Gateaux's derivative we only change the letters and say that they are more general. Shouldn't this come with some change in the formulation of the definition?

Comment: what do you mean the usual definition of directional derivatives don't hold? clearly if $V,W$ are Banach spaces, $A\subset V$ an open set, $f:A\to W$ a function and $a\in A$ and $v\in V$, we can still ask whether or not the limit $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+hv)-f(a)}{h}$ exists in $W$ (where $h\in\Bbb{R}$ and $h\neq 0$). We can ask about the existence of the limit because $W$ is a Banach space hence has a norm hence a distance metric hence a topology... $V=\Bbb{R}^n$ and $W=\Bbb{R}^m$ are simply special cases.

Comment: very often students only learn about differential calculus in $\Bbb{R}^n$, so it is the extension to more general spaces (Banach/Frechet etc) that is the generalization; not really the structure of the definitions.

Comment: So, summarizing, for a didatic purpose, we define the directional derivative in a way that could be "valid" for n-manifolds at it's best, and, for the sake of notation, we've established a more general definition, but who wishes to express the same thing? If  that's the case, the actual differences are in the application, not the definition?

Comment: valid for $n$-manifolds? manifolds don't have a vector space structure so for a manifold $M$, $a,v\in M$ and $h\in\Bbb{R}$ we can't talk about $a+hv$ (hence $f(a+hv)$ also doesn't make sense)

Comment: Well, since every point of a n-manifold has a neighborhood homeorphic to Rn, I felt like it could be valid under this extension.

Comment: If you choose different homeomorphisms, the limits could very well be different. Anyway, as long as you're working in the vector space context, you're right in your final sentence "the actual differences are in the application, not the definition".